# Get IP and name of devices on WIFI

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm working on a little application, the first step is to get IP and name of all devices connected to my wifi.
Actually I'm able to get only the BSSID of some devices in my wifi but not all

code is:

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            List<ScanResult> a=wifi.getScanResults();
            int j=0;

            while(j<a.size()){
                System.out.println(a.get(j).SSID);
                j++;
            }
```

how can I get what i want?

Comment: What you're doing is printing out the SSIDs of all the wireless access points the WifiManager detected from the scan. I.e. the names of the Wifi around you and not the devices that are connected to an access point.

Comment: oh...ok, so how can i get devices?

Comment: Tim K. linked a library below to do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

called Android Network Discovery and interested developers can get its source code from [github repo](https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery)